# Understanding gradients on Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I am trying to understand how the gradients are defined on a Riemannian manifold, at least in a shallow way. The wikipedia definition is as the following:

[image]

What I understand from this is, given a manifold $M$ with the metric $g$, the gradient of function $f$on the manifold $M$ is the vector field $(\nabla f)_x$ which produces for every $x \in M$ and $X_x \in T_xM$ a scalar $(\partial_{X}f)(x)$. According to the definition here, $(\partial_{X}f)(x)$ is equal to the directional derivative of $f$ at the direction of $X$, both evaluated at $x$. So, this should be $\nabla f(x)^TX_x$, if I understand correctly. But this understanding seems trivial; then the required $\nabla f$ will be just the evaluation of the function $f$'s gradient at each $x \in M$. And the last definition of $\partial_{X}f$ with the coordinate chart $\phi$ seems to tell something else; so I am confused here. What is the actual, correct interpretation of this definition?

Comment: You have the differential $df$ which is a section of the cotangent bundle. But the metric form identifies the cotangent bundle with the tangent bundle. In this identification $\nabla f$ is the section of the tangent bundle corresponding to $df$.

Answer (score 8):

I will try to convince you that there is no difference with what happens in "normal" calculus. Let's then start from $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ you have a natural inner product (the Euclidean product) which is given (in the orthonormal basis $\hat x, \hat y, \hat z$) by 
$\left<a,b\right> = a^t b$. This product defines an isomorphism A: $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ such that $A: a\mapsto \langle a,\cdot \rangle$.

To every function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ you can associate its differential $df$, which is the map $df: v\mapsto D_v(f)$ (directional derivative). Using the isomorphism $A$ given by the eucledian product, you can find a vector (called gradient of f, denoted by $\nabla f$), such that $\left<\nabla f , v\right> = df(v) = D_v(f)$. In the orthonormal basis $\hat x, \hat y, \hat z$, this means $(\nabla f)^k = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} $. This last formula is not true, however, in an arbitrary basis.

Note that the differential of f is the more general object, while its gradient exists thanks to the Euclidean scalar product.

On a Riemaniann manifold, the procedure is exactly the same! The differential is the more general object, defined in exactly the same way: $df(v) = v(f)$ (since $v$ is the generalization of a directional derivative!) and so is the gradient: $g(\nabla f, v) = df(v)$.

Answer (score 7):

Think of it in terms of *properties* we want the gradient to have. Properties come first, and formulas are then written out so that they satisfy those properties.

The essential properties of the gradient vector field $\nabla f$ are:

- $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the level sets of $f$
- $|\nabla f|$ is proportional to the rate of increase of $f$

The differential $df$ takes a vector field $X$ and returns a measurement of how quickly $f$ is increasing along the flow line of $X$. If $\nabla f$ has the properties above, then we should be able to obtain this measurement by taking the dot product of $X$ with the gradient field $\nabla f$. So the *defining property* of the vector field $\nabla f$ is that, for all vector fields $X$, we have:
$$ g(\nabla f, X) = df(X) = \partial_Xf $$

Comment: Given a $x \in M$, the differential $df_x$ is the vector with the partial derivatives wrt to every coordinate, right? So, is then the directional derivate definition above correct? How is this geometrically interpreted, in order to get more intuition? (Sorry if these are too obvious, I am not formally teached in differential geometry).

Answer (score 2):

The following is another, equivalent, point of view: the idea that a gradient gives you the direction of "steepest ascent".

The gradient applied to a function $f$ at $p$ should produce a tangent vector that in some sense maximizes the local change in $f$ when walking in the direction of the tangent vector. In order for this to make sense, we have to constrain the length of the vector (otherwise the target of this maximization is unbounded). But this is exactly what the Riemannian metric does, which is a way of specifying at each point a scalar product $\langle v,w\rangle_p=g_p(v,w)$ for any two vectors $v,w$ at $p$, in a way that depends smoothly on the point. We may then define a steepest direction of $f$ at $p$ as the unit vector that maximizes the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$

$$sf_p = \arg \max_{\langle v,v\rangle_p=1} vf= \arg \max_{\langle v,v\rangle_p=1} df_p(v), \tag1$$
and then we define the gradient as a scaled version that also takes into account how fast $f$ actually changes in that direction. We therefore multiply $sf_p$ by the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $sf_p$:
$$\text{grad} f_p=df_p(sf_p)\;sf_p.$$

It may then be shown that $\text{grad} f_p$ satisfies
$$\langle \text{grad} f_p, v \rangle_p = df_p(v) \tag2$$
for every tangent vector $v$. By the non-degeneracy of the scalar product, this then uniquely defines $\text{grad} f_p$ in terms of the inverse metric tensor. In order to show (2), we may write down a Lagrangian for the constrained optimization problem (1):
$$\mathcal{L}(v)=df_p(v)+\lambda(\langle v,v\rangle_p-1),$$
where $\lambda$ is some Lagrange multiplier. The first variation of this reads
$$\mathcal{L}(v+\delta v)-\mathcal{L}(v)=df_p(\delta v)+2\lambda \langle v,\delta v\rangle_p+\text{higher-order terms} = 0, \quad \forall\delta v,$$
from which we obtain (by setting $v=\delta v=sf_p$) that $-2\lambda=df_p(sf_p)$ and then by plugging this back into the first variation for $v=sf_p$,
$$\langle \text{grad} f_p, \delta v \rangle_p=df_p(sf_p)\langle sf_p, \delta v \rangle_p = df_p(\delta v), \quad \forall\delta v.$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think this is the answer which brings me closest to understand everything completely, but still I am lost at some point. So, the directional derivative of $f$, at a point $p$ is defined in a general Euclidean space as $df_p(v)= \dfrac{df(p + hv)}{dh}|_{h=0}$. But here, we just have the notion of a direction $v$ at $p$ on the tangent space to $p$ and not a precise definition of $df_p(v)$. However we can still proceed to the Lagrangian $L(v)$ and calculate $grad f_p$ from that Lagrangian. How is this possible? Sorry if I am missing something too obvious.

Comment: A second thing: The first variation is $L(v + \delta v) - L(v) = df_p(v + \delta v) + \lambda(\langle v + \delta v,v + \delta v\rangle_p-1) - df_p(v)-\lambda(\langle v,v\rangle_p-1)$ which then becomes $df_p(v + \delta v) + \lambda(\langle v ,v\rangle_p + 2\langle v ,\delta v\rangle_p + \langle \delta v ,\delta v\rangle_p -1)- df_p(v)-\lambda(\langle v,v\rangle_p-1)$. So, how does it simplify to $df_p(\delta v)+2\lambda \langle v,\delta v\rangle_p$?

Comment: @Ufuk: The differential in a Euclidean space is rather $df_p(v)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(p+h v)-f(p)}{h}$. In a general smooth manifold you take some smooth curve with $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$ and then $vf_p=df_p(v)=\frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))|_{t=0}$. This is well-defined. Regarding your secod question: the simplification is due to the linearity of $df_p$ and the bilinearity of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_p$ (which you already exploited). You can drop the term $\langle\delta v,\delta v\rangle_p$ for the first variation because that is of order $\delta v^2$.